How to copy value from parent work item into child work item in Azure Devops using Power Automate
I use User Story as my parent work item. I have tasks attached to each User Story and would like to copy the value from the Sizing field to each of those tasks.
I found this example, but the screen shots showed in the instructions are different from what I have available in my flow setup: https://www.azuredevopsguide.com/copying-values-from-parent-to-child-workitems-in-azure-devops-using-a-powerautomate-flow/
I don't see "method" or "Relative URI" fields in the "Get work item details" settings.
power automate comparison


I don't see "method" or "Relative URI" fields in the "Get work item details" settings.

Your action is "Get work item details", but in your example, it is using the Action “Send HTTP Request to Azure DevOps" with this Work Items - Get Work Item REST API.

So, you should choose the "Send HTTP Request to Azure DevOps" when you add a new action.

Then you will see the "method" or "Relative URI" fields. That example renamed action from the "Send HTTP Request to Azure DevOps" to "Get the Details of the Workitem".

